# How to get Start Date of current iteration of Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I would like to do a query on Azure Devops considering the condition:

work item = Task and

created date < **["Start date of @CurrentIteration"]** and

iteration path = @CurrentIteration

How can I perform this contintion (**["Start date of @CurrentIteration"]**) on Azure Devops?

Comment: To me the filtering of the current date and the iteration path would return the same results. Can you explain what it is you expect this will provide you? i.e. what is the question you want to answer? Perhaps there are other ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: My intention is to know it a task was created during the current iteration or if it was planned before current iteration.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I perform this contintion (["Start date of
>   @CurrentIteration"]) on Azure Devops?

As I know there's no predefined macros that represents the start date of `@CurrentIteration`. We have to go `Sprints` tab manually to get the start date of current Iteration and then use that value in Query.

You can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops) for more details: *To list work items based on when they were created, closed, resolved, or changed state—use @Today or specify dates. For queries that list work items based on their assignment to a team's current sprint, use @CurrentIteration.*

For now we don't have such macros like `@StartOfCurrentIteration`. But it would be better if we have one macros used to represent the start date of `@CurrentIteration`. So I suggest you can post one feature request(Suggest a feature) of this macros in our User Voice forum-[Developer Community Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).

[image]

Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps. Hope my answer makes some help:)

Comment: Done! https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/888712/new-macro-like.html